# why does running "bash &" in shell stops immediately?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, background-process

I am trying to test having different bash shells as children of a parent shell. I am trying to start a shell in background to see but it stops immediately and stays in background. What is causing this behaviour?

```
➜ bash &
[1] 59521

[1]+  Stopped                 bash
```

Comment: Can't read input in the background, so as soon as it tries to read from stdin it gets stopped.. Connect its stdin to somewhere other than a terminal and this won't happen.